# How to develop using android libraries in a simple java project (without using dalvik and such)

Tags: java, android, project

As I am very pissed off of using the emulator to develop any Java class, I thought of setting up a project in Eclipse and instead of the usual JRE I linked to the Android.jar (version 2.1) that usually the Android projects link to. I don't mean to use this to develop Layouts or other specific platform things, I was just trying to create a class that uses HttpClient. It miserably crashes like this.

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.(AbstractHttpClient.java:5)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.(DefaultHttpClient.java:7)
>     at
>   AdsCatcher.(AdsCatcher.java:26)
>     at TestAll.main(TestAll.java:10)

Stub! I mean I'd like to develop libraries (and test them) so that when I go to the emulator I don't have to deal with them. Is there a good way to do this? This seems not to work for some reason.

Comment: "It miserably crashes"... when? What are you doing to make this happen? Running the code? Merely compiling it? More details and less attitude might allow other to help you

Comment: If there is an Exception, it means that I tried running some stuff isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

This will not work, sorry. The `android.jar` file, as the error message indicates, contains only stubs of the Android API. This makes sense, since that API cannot work outside of Android -- the `android.jar` file is just there for compilation.

For class libraries you are working on that have no dependencies on Android, you are welcome to create a standard JRE Eclipse project that generates a JAR that you then use in your Android project.

In your case, you *may* be able to create a class library using the JRE that uses HttpClient. The latest version from Apache may differ slightly from the version in Android, though, so while *probably* you will be OK, there's a chance you will run into runtime errors due to changes in method signatures and such (`VerifyError`).

Comment: I was suspecting this, what you say makes a lot of sense... Anyway in this particular case HttpClient is so different that even the basic Apache tutorial is not working on Android :(

Comment: @gotch4: Make sure you are looking at the HttpClient 4.x tutorial. HttpClient completely overhauled their API between the 3.x and 4.x series.