# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub , viewed all thread but of no use

Tags: java, opencv, javacv, java.util.logging

This is a face recognition class which read the faces from data folder but when i run this code i came up with the error given below. All the [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213533/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-runtimeexception-stub) Threads couldn't solve my problem. any help will be appreciated.

```
 public  class FaceRecognition {

          /** the logger */
          private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FaceRecognition.class);
          //JavaLoggingClassName.loginfo();
          /** the number of training faces */
          private int nTrainFaces = 0;
          private int width = 320;
          private int height = 240;
          /** the training face image array */
          IplImage[] trainingFaceImgArr = null;//IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
          /** the test face image array */
          IplImage[] testFaceImgArr= null;
          //IplImage image = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
         // Bitmap mBitmap;
          //IplImage image = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
          //private Bitmap mBitmap;

          /** the person number array **/
          CvMat personNumTruthMat;
          /** the number of persons **/
          int nPersons;
          /** the person names */
          final List personNames = new ArrayList<>();
          /** the number of eigenvalues */
          int nEigens = 0;
          /** eigenvectors */
          IplImage[] eigenVectArr;
          /** eigenvalues */
          CvMat eigenValMat;
          /** the average image */
          IplImage pAvgTrainImg;
          /** the projected training faces */
          CvMat projectedTrainFaceMat;

          /** Constructs a new FaceRecognition instance. */
          public FaceRecognition() {
          }
          //JavaLoggingClassName.loginfo()
          /** Trains from the data in the given training text index file, and store the trained data into the file 'data/facedata.xml'.
           *
           * @param trainingFileName the given training text index file
           */
          public void learn(final String trainingFileName) {
            int i;

            // load training data
            LOGGER.info("===========================================");
            //IplImage 
            LOGGER.info("Loading the training images in " + trainingFileName);
            //IplImage image = IplImage.create(width, height, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);
            //mBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(image.getByteBuffer());
            try
            {
            trainingFaceImgArr /*mBitmap*/ = loadFaceImgArray(trainingFileName);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {

                Log.i("ERROR", "ERROR in Code: " + e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            nTrainFaces = trainingFaceImgArr.length;
            LOGGER.info("Got " + nTrainFaces + " training images");
            if (nTrainFaces < 3) {
              LOGGER.error("Need 3 or more training faces\n"
                      + "Input file contains only " + nTrainFaces);
              return;
            }


            LOGGER.info("created projectedTrainFaceMat with " + nTrainFaces + " (nTrainFaces) rows and " + nEigens + " (nEigens) columns");
            if (nTrainFaces < 5) {
              LOGGER.info("projectedTrainFaceMat contents:\n" + oneChannelCvMatToString(projectedTrainFaceMat));
            }

            /* @param szFileTest the index file of test images


            } catch (IOException ex) {
              throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }

            LOGGER.info("Data loaded from '" + filename + "': (" + nFaces + " images of " + nPersons + " people).");
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("People: ");
            if (nPersons > 0) {
              stringBuilder.append("<").append(personNames.get(0)).append(">");
            }
            for (i = 1; i < nPersons && i < personNames.size(); i++) {
              stringBuilder.append(", <").append(personNames.get(i)).append(">");
            }
            LOGGER.info(stringBuilder.toString());

            return faceImgArr;
          }

          /** Does the Principal Component Analysis, finding the average image and the eigenfaces that represent any image in the given dataset. */
          private void doPCA() {
            int i;
            CvTermCriteria calcLimit;
            CvSize faceImgSize = new CvSize();

            // set the number of eigenvalues to use
            nEigens = nTrainFaces - 1;

            LOGGER.info("allocating images for principal component analysis, using " + nEigens + (nEigens == 1 ? " eigenvalue" : " eigenvalues"));

            // allocate the eigenvector images
            faceImgSize.width(trainingFaceImgArr[0].width());
            faceImgSize.height(trainingFaceImgArr[0].height());
            eigenVectArr = new IplImage[nEigens];
            for (i = 0; i < nEigens; i++) {
              eigenVectArr[i] = cvCreateImage(
                      faceImgSize, // size
                      IPL_DEPTH_32F, // depth
                      1); // channels
            }

            // allocate the eigenvalue array
            eigenValMat = cvCreateMat(
                    1, // rows
                    nEigens, // cols
                    CV_32FC1); // type, 32-bit float, 1 channel

            // allocate the averaged image
            pAvgTrainImg = cvCreateImage(
                    faceImgSize, // size
                    IPL_DEPTH_32F, // depth
                    1); // channels

            // set the PCA termination criterion
            calcLimit = cvTermCriteria(
                    CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, // type
                    nEigens, // max_iter
                    1); // epsilon

            LOGGER.info("computing average image, eigenvalues and eigenvectors");
            // compute average image, eigenvalues, and eigenvectors
            cvCalcEigenObjects(
                    nTrainFaces, // nObjects
                    new PointerPointer(trainingFaceImgArr), // input
                    new PointerPointer(eigenVectArr), // output
                    CV_EIGOBJ_NO_CALLBACK, // ioFlags
                    0, // ioBufSize
                    null, // userData
                    calcLimit,
                    pAvgTrainImg, // avg
                    eigenValMat.data_fl()); // eigVals

            LOGGER.info("normalizing the eigenvectors");
            cvNormalize(
                    eigenValMat, // src (CvArr)
                    eigenValMat, // dst (CvArr)
                    1, // a
                    0, // b
                    CV_L1, // norm_type
                    null); // mask
          }

          /** Stores the training data to the file 'data/facedata.xml'. */
          private void storeTrainingData() {
            CvFileStorage fileStorage;
            int i;

            LOGGER.info("writing data/facedata.xml");

            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage(
                    "data/facedata.xml", // filename
                    null, // memstorage
                    CV_STORAGE_WRITE, // flags
                    null); // encoding

            // Store the person names. Added by Shervin.
            cvWriteInt(
                    fileStorage, // fs
                    "nPersons", // name
                    nPersons); // value

            for (i = 0; i < nPersons; i++) {
              String varname = "personName_" + (i + 1);
              String personame=(String)personNames.get(i);
              cvWriteString(
                      fileStorage, // fs
                      varname, // name
                      personame, // string
                      0); // quote
            }

            // store all the data
            cvWriteInt(
                    fileStorage, // fs
                    "nEigens", // name
                    nEigens); // value

            cvWriteInt(
                    fileStorage, // fs
                    "nTrainFaces", // name
                    nTrainFaces); // value

            cvWrite(
                    fileStorage, // fs
                    "trainPersonNumMat", // name
                    personNumTruthMat, // value
                    cvAttrList()); // attributes

            cvWrite(
                    fileStorage, // fs
                    "eigenValMat", // name
                    eigenValMat, // value
                    cvAttrList()); // attributes

            cvWrite(
                    fileStorage, // fs
                    "projectedTrainFaceMat", // name
                    projectedTrainFaceMat,
                    cvAttrList()); // value

            cvWrite(fileStorage, // fs
                    "avgTrainImg", // name
                    pAvgTrainImg, // value
                    cvAttrList()); // attributes

            for (i = 0; i < nEigens; i++) {
              String varname = "eigenVect_" + i;
              cvWrite(
                      fileStorage, // fs
                      varname, // name
                      eigenVectArr[i], // value
                      cvAttrList()); // attributes
            }

            // release the file-storage interface
            cvReleaseFileStorage(fileStorage);
          }

          /** Opens the training data from the file 'data/facedata.xml'.
           *
           * @param pTrainPersonNumMat
           * @return the person numbers during training, or null if not successful
           */
          private CvMat loadTrainingData() {
            LOGGER.info("loading training data");
            CvMat pTrainPersonNumMat = null; // the person numbers during training
            CvFileStorage fileStorage;
            int i;

            // create a file-storage interface
            fileStorage = cvOpenFileStorage(
                    "data/facedata.xml", // filename
                    null, // memstorage
                    CV_STORAGE_READ, // flags
                    null); // encoding
            if (fileStorage == null) {
              LOGGER.error("Can't open training database file 'data/facedata.xml'.");
              return null;
            }

            // Load the person names.
            personNames.clear();        // Make sure it starts as empty.
            nPersons = cvReadIntByName(
                    fileStorage, // fs
                    null, // map
                    "nPersons", // name
                    0); // default_value
            if (nPersons == 0) {
              LOGGER.error("No people found in the training database 'data/facedata.xml'.");
              return null;
            } else {
              LOGGER.info(nPersons + " persons read from the training database");
            }

            // Load each person's name.
            for (i = 0; i < nPersons; i++) {
              String sPersonName;
              String varname = "personName_" + (i + 1);
              sPersonName = cvReadStringByName(
                      fileStorage, // fs
                      null, // map
                      varname,
                      "");
              personNames.add(sPersonName);
            }
            LOGGER.info("person names: " + personNames);

            // Load the data
            nEigens = cvReadIntByName(
                    fileStorage, // fs
                    null, // map
                    "nEigens",
                    0); // default_value
            nTrainFaces = cvReadIntByName(
                    fileStorage,
                    null, // map
                    "nTrainFaces",
                    0); // default_value
            Pointer pointer = cvReadByName(
                    fileStorage, // fs
                    null, // map
                    "trainPersonNumMat", // name
                    cvAttrList()); // attributes
            pTrainPersonNumMat = new CvMat(pointer);

            pointer = cvReadByName(
                    fileStorage, // fs
                    null, // map
                    "eigenValMat", // nmae
                    cvAttrList()); // attributes
            eigenValMat = new CvMat(pointer);

            pointer = cvReadByName(
                    fileStorage, // fs
                    null, // map
                    "projectedTrainFaceMat", // name
                    cvAttrList()); // attributes
            projectedTrainFaceMat = new CvMat(pointer);

            pointer = cvReadByName(
                    fileStorage,
                    null, // map
                    "avgTrainImg",
                    cvAttrList()); // attributes
            pAvgTrainImg = new IplImage(pointer);

            eigenVectArr = new IplImage[nTrainFaces];
            for (i = 0; i < nEigens; i++) {
              String varname = "eigenVect_" + i;
              pointer = cvReadByName(
                      fileStorage,
                      null, // map
                      varname,
                      cvAttrList()); // attributes
              eigenVectArr[i] = new IplImage(pointer);
            }

            // release the file-storage interface
            cvReleaseFileStorage(fileStorage);

            LOGGER.info("Training data loaded (" + nTrainFaces + " training images of " + nPersons + " people)");
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.append("People: ");
            if (nPersons > 0) {
              stringBuilder.append("<").append(personNames.get(0)).append(">");
            }
            for (i = 1; i < nPersons; i++) {
              stringBuilder.append(", <").append(personNames.get(i)).append(">");
            }
            LOGGER.info(stringBuilder.toString());

            return pTrainPersonNumMat;
          }

          /** Saves all the eigenvectors as images, so that they can be checked. */
          private void storeEigenfaceImages() {
            // Store the average image to a file
            LOGGER.info("Saving the image of the average face as 'data/out_averageImage.bmp'");
            cvSaveImage("data/out_averageImage.bmp", pAvgTrainImg);

            // Create a large image made of many eigenface images.
            // Must also convert each eigenface image to a normal 8-bit UCHAR image instead of a 32-bit float image.
            LOGGER.info("Saving the " + nEigens + " eigenvector images as 'data/out_eigenfaces.bmp'");

            if (nEigens > 0) {
              // Put all the eigenfaces next to each other.
              int COLUMNS = 8;        // Put upto 8 images on a row.
              int nCols = Math.min(nEigens, COLUMNS);
              int nRows = 1 + (nEigens / COLUMNS);        // Put the rest on new rows.
              int w = eigenVectArr[0].width();
              int h = eigenVectArr[0].height();
              CvSize size = cvSize(nCols * w, nRows * h);
              final IplImage bigImg = cvCreateImage(
                      size,
                      IPL_DEPTH_8U, // depth, 8-bit Greyscale UCHAR image
                      1);        // channels
              for (int i = 0; i < nEigens; i++) {
                // Get the eigenface image.
                IplImage byteImg = convertFloatImageToUcharImage(eigenVectArr[i]);
                // Paste it into the correct position.
                int x = w * (i % COLUMNS);
                int y = h * (i / COLUMNS);
                CvRect ROI = cvRect(x, y, w, h);
                cvSetImageROI(
                        bigImg, // image
                        ROI); // rect
                cvCopy(
                        byteImg, // src
                        bigImg, // dst
                        null); // mask
                cvResetImageROI(bigImg);
                cvReleaseImage(byteImg);
              }
              cvSaveImage(
                      "data/out_eigenfaces.bmp", // filename
                      bigImg); // image
              cvReleaseImage(bigImg);
            }
          }

          /** Converts the given float image to an unsigned character image.
           *
           * @param srcImg the given float image
           * @return the unsigned character image
           */
          private IplImage convertFloatImageToUcharImage(IplImage srcImg) {
            IplImage dstImg;
            if ((srcImg != null) && (srcImg.width() > 0 && srcImg.height() > 0)) {
              // Spread the 32bit floating point pixels to fit within 8bit pixel range.
              CvPoint minloc = new CvPoint();
              CvPoint maxloc = new CvPoint();
              double[] minVal = new double[1];
              double[] maxVal = new double[1];
              cvMinMaxLoc(srcImg, minVal, maxVal, minloc, maxloc, null);
              // Deal with NaN and extreme values, since the DFT seems to give some NaN results.
              if (minVal[0] < -1e30) {
                minVal[0] = -1e30;
              }
              if (maxVal[0] > 1e30) {
                maxVal[0] = 1e30;
              }
              if (maxVal[0] - minVal[0] == 0.0f) {
                maxVal[0] = minVal[0] + 0.001;  // remove potential divide by zero errors.
              }                        // Convert the format
              dstImg = cvCreateImage(cvSize(srcImg.width(), srcImg.height()), 8, 1);
              cvConvertScale(srcImg, dstImg, 255.0 / (maxVal[0] - minVal[0]), -minVal[0] * 255.0 / (maxVal[0] - minVal[0]));
              return dstImg;
            }
            return null;
          }

          /** Find the most likely person based on a detection. Returns the index, and stores the confidence value into pConfidence.
           *
           * @param projectedTestFace the projected test face
           * @param pConfidencePointer a pointer containing the confidence value
           * @param iTestFace the test face index
           * @return the index
           */
          private int findNearestNeighbor(float projectedTestFace[], FloatPointer pConfidencePointer) {
            double leastDistSq = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            int i = 0;
            int iTrain = 0;
            int iNearest = 0;

            LOGGER.info("................");
            LOGGER.info("find nearest neighbor from " + nTrainFaces + " training faces");
            for (iTrain = 0; iTrain < nTrainFaces; iTrain++) {
              //LOGGER.info("considering training face " + (iTrain + 1));
              double distSq = 0;

              for (i = 0; i < nEigens; i++) {
                //LOGGER.debug("  projected test face distance from eigenface " + (i + 1) + " is " + projectedTestFace[i]);

                float projectedTrainFaceDistance = (float) projectedTrainFaceMat.get(iTrain, i);
                float d_i = projectedTestFace[i] - projectedTrainFaceDistance;
                distSq += d_i * d_i; // / eigenValMat.data_fl().get(i);  // Mahalanobis distance (might give better results than Eucalidean distance)
        //          if (iTrain < 5) {
        //            LOGGER.info("    ** projected training face " + (iTrain + 1) + " distance from eigenface " + (i + 1) + " is " + projectedTrainFaceDistance);
        //            LOGGER.info("    distance between them " + d_i);
        //            LOGGER.info("    distance squared " + distSq);
        //          }
              }

              if (distSq < leastDistSq) {
                leastDistSq = distSq;
                iNearest = iTrain;
                LOGGER.info("  training face " + (iTrain + 1) + " is the new best match, least squared distance: " + leastDistSq);
              }
            }

            // Return the confidence level based on the Euclidean distance,
            // so that similar images should give a confidence between 0.5 to 1.0,
            // and very different images should give a confidence between 0.0 to 0.5.
            float pConfidence = (float) (1.0f - Math.sqrt(leastDistSq / (float) (nTrainFaces * nEigens)) / 255.0f);
            pConfidencePointer.put(pConfidence);

            LOGGER.info("training face " + (iNearest + 1) + " is the final best match, confidence " + pConfidence);
            return iNearest;
          }

          /** Returns a string representation of the given float array.
           *
           * @param floatArray the given float array
           * @return a string representation of the given float array
           */
          private String floatArrayToString(final float[] floatArray) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            boolean isFirst = true;
            stringBuilder.append('[');
            for (int i = 0; i < floatArray.length; i++) {
              if (isFirst) {
                isFirst = false;
              } else {
                stringBuilder.append(", ");
              }
              stringBuilder.append(floatArray[i]);
            }
            stringBuilder.append(']');

            return stringBuilder.toString();
          }

          /** Returns a string representation of the given float pointer.
           *
           * @param floatPointer the given float pointer
           * @return a string representation of the given float pointer
           */
          private String floatPointerToString(final FloatPointer floatPointer) {
            final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            boolean isFirst = true;
            stringBuilder.append('[');
            for (int i = 0; i < floatPointer.capacity(); i++) {
              if (isFirst) {
                isFirst = false;
              } else {
                stringBuilder.append(", ");
              }
              stringBuilder.append(floatPointer.get(i));
            }
            stringBuilder.append(']');

            return stringBuilder.toString();
          }

          /** Returns a string representation of the given one-channel CvMat object.
           *
           * @param cvMat the given CvMat object
           * @return a string representation of the given CvMat object
           */
          public String oneChannelCvMatToString(final CvMat cvMat) {
            //Preconditions
            if (cvMat.channels() != 1) {
              throw new RuntimeException("illegal argument - CvMat must have one channel");
            }

            final int type = cvMat.type();
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("[ ");
            for (int i = 0; i < cvMat.rows(); i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < cvMat.cols(); j++) {
                if (type == CV_32FC1 || type == CV_32SC1) {
                  s.append(cvMat.get(i, j));
                } else {
                  throw new RuntimeException("illegal argument - CvMat must have one channel and type of float or signed integer");
                }
                if (j < cvMat.cols() - 1) {
                  s.append(", ");
                }
              }
              if (i < cvMat.rows() - 1) {
                s.append("\n  ");
              }
            }
            s.append(" ]");
            return s.toString();
          }

          /** Executes this application.
           *
           * @param args the command line arguments
           */

          public static void main(final String[] args) {
              BasicConfigurator.configure();
            // PropertyConfigurator.configure(args[0]);
            // if(args[0]!=null)
             /*{
                System.out.println("null index");
             }
             else continue;
             */
             final FaceRecognition faceRecognition = new FaceRecognition();
         //   main myMain = new main();
           // myMain.FaceRecognition();

            //faceRecognition.learn("data/some-training-faces.txt");
          //  faceRecognition.learn("G:\\android_support\\javacv-examples\\OpenCV2_Cookbook\\data\\all10.txt");
            faceRecognition.learn("data/all100.txt");
            //faceRecognition.recognizeFileList("data/some-test-faces.txt");
           // faceRecognition.recognizeFileList("G:\\android_support\\javacv-examples\\OpenCV2_Cookbook\\data\\lower3.txt");
            faceRecognition.recognizeFileList("data/lower3.txt");
          }
        }
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:9)
    at FaceRecognition.learn(FaceRecognition.java:126)
    at FaceRecognition.main(FaceRecognition.java:846)
```

Comment: Read this blog and follow the stpes http://jeffangelini.com/java-lang-runtimeexception-stub/

Comment: sorry followed ur link but still facing the same problem

Comment: @Er. Nikhil I have news for you: Not everybody used eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you try to test android classes on the host computer. Perhaps using JUnit. **That does not work**. There are two options open:

1. If possible move the functionality into library so that no  `android` packages are used. For example use `java.util.logging` instead of `android.util.Log`.
2. Use android instrumentation tests (google it).

And if you use Maven: remember that the android library is `<scope>provided</scope>`.