# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! error when using amazon sqs.

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I get the following error when i'm trying to initialize the amazon sqs client with my credentials.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub!
    at org.apache.http.params.AbstractHttpParams.<init>(AbstractHttpParams.java:5)
    at org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams.<init>(BasicHttpParams.java:6)
    at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:73)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:111)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:60)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.<init>(AmazonSQSClient.java:151)
    at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.<init>(AmazonSQSClient.java:132)
```

Here's the code that's causing it :

```
 public class SQSControllerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        AmazonSQS sqs = new AmazonSQSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials("xxxx", "xxxx"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What SDK (and version) are you using?

Comment: This happened to me when I used classes from Android SDK in a standard java project. This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3896064/how-to-develop-using-android-libraries-in-a-simple-java-project-without-using-d

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue.  It is a classpath issue.

I believe that the Android SDK has a copy of AbstractHttpParams that has this method stubbed out, so you want the http-core jar ahead of it on your build-path.

Hope this helps.[image]