# Android library project does not compile its (java project) dependencies into its jar

Tags: android, eclipse, android-library

I have an ***android libary project*** - `MonitoringModel` - which depends on a ***regular java project*** - `Helpers` (the dependency was set in the java build path > Projects. The `Helpers` project was ticked in the "order and export" tab of the `MonitoringModel`). `MonitoringModel` produces a jar which I drop to the libs folder of a servlet project as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18594605/281545). All was fine till *the servlet* needed a method from the `Helpers` project :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gr/uoa/di/java/helpers/Utils
 at gr.uoa.di.monitoring.model.Battery$BatteryFields$1.parse(Battery.java:59)
 at gr.uoa.di.monitoring.model.Battery$BatteryFields$1.parse(Battery.java:1)
 at gr.uoa.di.monitoring.model.Battery.parse(Battery.java:117)
 ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gr.uoa.di.java.helpers.Utils
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
```

I realized then that the exported jar (from the `MonitoringModel`) had not the `Helpers` packages. The `Helpers` project does not create any jar so I tried adding its `bin/` folder as [Add Class Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661110/how-do-i-include-class-files-in-my-project-in-eclipse-java))

[image]

adding it also in "order and export" tab :

[image]

but still no joy.

So how should I set this up ?

**RECAP :** What I am after is a way to *add a regular java project into an android library project* and have this compiled *in the jar of the android library project* somehow.  Τhe problem is not so much that the (java) classes are not exported - as that the methods that use those java classes are not *compiled* in the jar *correctly*. So when they are called the exception above is thrown. The `Battery$BatteryFields$1.parse` method is [here](https://github.com/Utumno/MonitoringModel/blob/master/src/gr/uoa/di/monitoring/model/Battery.java#L56).

***NB : adding the `Helpers` project directly to the servlets project does not prevent the exception***. The exception is thrown because when `MonitoringModel.parse()` calls `Helpers.listToString()` the latter is nowhere to be found *in monitoringmodel.jar*
For the moment I had to [simply add](https://github.com/Utumno/MonitoringModel/commit/c8d1fc2eb447ea07974be1c5168387285f8c0be3) (see Copy Paste) the `Helpers` *packages* to the `MonitoringModel`.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM: Unfortunately no - but I am still interested in an answer. Feel free to place a bounty :D

Comment: I moved the build process to maven and seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @MLProgrammer-CiM: I don't do maven but please post a detailed answer (for maven noobs) and I will go through

Answer (score 0):

**You have to compile your Helper Java Project independent, and export a JAR like a normal Java JAR**

Then, you have to add this JAR to Monitor Android Library LIBS folder.

Now you can add the Monitor Android Library to another project (From Android Libraries box), and it will have the sources that you need.

The problem is that the Project Tab does not compile anymore the referenced project since some ADT Version, so it's useless.

Comment: Thanks for answer but please read more carefully - while I used the projects tab initially I switched to the Libraries tab - and most important : I want to use the MonitoringModel in a NON android project - this is possible as I said in the question (link again) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18594605/281545). I am very interested in this - maybe a post in the android dev group is in order.

Comment: Also please provide more detailed instructions on jaring the helpers project - preferably some automated way (ant ?).